# If everything slowed down around you, but you were just as fast you are normally, would you jump higher?

Tags: thought-experiment

If everything slowed down around you, but you were just as fast you are normally, would you jump higher? I am thinking velocity would increase, thus the force generated would be stronger, but I am not sure what physics say about this. What are the conditions that need to be true in order for the assertion to be true?

By everything slowed down, I mean people are moving slower than usual while you are still moving at normal speed as if you slowed time for other people, which is impossible.

Comment: You need to more carefully define what "everything slowed down around you" means and why you would expect this to affect jump height. It's not clear what situation you're describing here imo.

Comment: Let's change reference frames and ask the same question.  If everything around you kept its "normal" speed, and your speed increased, would you jump higher?

Comment: I think he may be asking what would happen if the earths rotation speed was slowed - bringing down centripetal/fugal force? - making it easier to jump higher?

Comment: "What if" questions like this one lead to all sorts of trouble when it comes to "what physics says about it", if they aren't formulated in an excruciatingly precise way (in terms of the exact mechanism involved), because once you try to scrutinize them, they break down in all sorts of ways. One way to try and get around it is to leave physics operating normally, and change the psychological perception of the rate at which time passes (world stays as it was, it just seems slowed down to you). You suspend disbelief there; scrutinizing how *that* works leads down the same kind of rabbit hole.

Comment: @Drjh Less centrifugal force will make  jumping harder, at least on or near the equator.

Comment: @AdrianHoward I was stating what I thought the OP was asking. Note the question marks in my comment.

Comment: If something impossible happened, what would be the consequences? Physics can't answer this. Physics isn't about how impossible things work.